# Search box: which phtml is getChildHtml using

Tags: magento-1.7, frontend, search, phtml

I am using Magento 1.7.
I am not sure of how `getChildHtml()` works. I have a piece of code in `header.phtml`,

```
echo $this->getChildHtml('topSearch');
```

used for showing the search box in my page. But I am not sure of which `.phtml` is using. First I thought it was using `form.mini.phtml` under `app/design/frontend/default/custom_theme/template/catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml`, but after enabling path hints in the Admin, it seems it's using another one.

I see that getChildHtml() is used a bit everywhere, and I see the idea of what it is used for, but I don't understand how it exactly works.

I need to know how can I define the string passed as parameter to `getChildHtml()`, and if there is an associated `.phtml`. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Ok. So getChildHtml() takes name or alias(if present) of a block. We use it to call a child block from inside of a parent block. It mostly gets defined in layout xml files.

Comment: Example go to `app\design\frontend\base\default\template\catalog\product\view.phtml` open it. Check `$this->getChildHtml('addto')` line. Now go to `catalog.xml` inside `app\design\frontend\base\default\layout` and search for it. You will find this line `<block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.addto" as="addto" template="catalog/product/view/addto.phtml"/>` which is a child block to `<block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/view.phtml">` this parent block.

Comment: Thank you! You can add an answer with the explanation and I'll accept it if you would like to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getChildHtml()` takes name or alias (if present) of a block. We use it to call a child block from inside of a parent block. It mostly gets defined in layout xml files.

Example go to `app\design\frontend\base\default\template\catalog\product\vi‌​ew.phtml` and open it. Check `$this->getChildHtml('addto')` line.

Now go to `catalog.xml` inside `app\design\frontend\base\default\layout` and search for it. You will find this line:

`<block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.addto" as="addto" template="catalog/product/view/addto.phtml"/>`

**which is a child block to this parent block:**

`<block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/view.phtml">`

Answer (score 1):

getChildHtml is the magento function defined under app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php

The phtml files are set dynamically from xml like this in catalogsearch.xml

```
<reference name="header">
<block type="core/template" name="top.search" as="topSearch" template="catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml"/>
```

and then these are loaded by alias name (defined here as="topSearch")  Magento to the frontend.